# How to add key-value in the Json Object in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have one JSON object.

```
def secretJson = readJSON text: secret
def props =  secretJson.SecretString
println secretJson.SecretString

Output:
{"Name":"welcome","Env":"test","Region":"us-east-1","Cloud":"AWS"}
```

can we append the key and value to this object?

for example:
{"Name":"welcome","Env":"test","Region":"us-east-1","Cloud":"AWS","readOnlyHost":"value"}